# Angular 1.5 component dependency injection

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I've been trying to use the new Angular 1.5 `component` syntax in a project, but I can't figure out how to inject a dependency into the component definition.

Here's my attempt at refactoring an existing directive to a component:

```
angular
    .module('app.myModule')
    .component('row', {
      bindings: {
        details: '@',
        zip: '@'
      },
      controller: 'RowController',
      templateUrl: basePath + 'modules/row.html' // basePath needs to be injected
    })
```

For various reasons, we inject the constant `basePath` into all of our directives as part of the templateUrl.

How do I do this on a component, since the component definition is not a function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a function for `templateUrl` to construct URL. However, unlike the one for directives, component `templateUrl` function is *injectable* (ref [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#comparison-between-directive-definition-and-component-definition)), which means that you can inject constant (or any other injectable service) into it. Exactly what you need:

```
.component('row', {
  bindings: {
    details: '@',
    zip: '@'
  },
  controller: 'RowController',
  templateUrl: function(basePath, $rootScope) { // $rootScope is an example here
    return basePath + 'modules/row.html'
  }
})
```

Minification-safe array notation is also supported:

```
templateUrl: ['basePath', '$rootScope', function(basePath, $rootScope) {
  return basePath + 'modules/row.html'
}]
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/jAIqkzZGnaEVPaUjyBrJ?p=preview

Comment: Perfect! It didn't occur to me to make templateUrl into a function.